# Reading csv files with quoted multiline fields in Python 3

Tags: csv, python-3.x

Variants of this have been asked before, but the handling of file I/O changed markedly between Python 2 and 3, and I haven't found anything that works.

My environment is Python 3.4.1 on Windows

csv files, e.g. those produced by Excel, can contain multi-line quoted strings which can have line feeds (hex 0A) within a single field.  How can I get these to be parsed properly rather than being interpreted as the end of an input line?

Here's a sample .csv file with two rows (in addition to the label row).  I can get my inputs in either utf-8 or utf-16, if it matters:

```
Column 1 Column 2
12345       single line of text
23456       "text with a newline here >
            < that should remain in one cell"
```

This code:

```
reader = csv.reader(open('Test.csv', newline=''), skipinitialspace = True)
for row in reader:
    print(', '.join(row))
```

Produces this result:

```
Column 1, Column 2
12345, single line of text
23456, text with a newline here >
< that should remain in one cell
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: Your output is just what I would expect, as the newline is printed as well... But you expected something different, I suppose. What is it you did expect?

Comment: Did you get your answer?

Comment: Is your actual input comma-separated or tab-separated? It can't be space-separated like it is in your question because then there would be no good way to tell columns apart. Please update your question with a more representative input that makes your problem reproducible. `csv.reader` has no problem handling a cell that contains a linefeed otherwise. Demo: https://ideone.com/ESlLOk